# Errorlevel in batch file not working

Tags: batch-file, sqlcmd

I'm trying to delete the database using  sqlcmd  with a batch script. The problem I was facing is the code isnot entering the errorhandler block if mytest database is not available in the sql.

```
@echo off
@echo IF ELSE DEMO
sqlcmd -S <servername> -U <username> -P <password> -Q "DROP DATABASE Mytest"  
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto err_handler
goto done

:err_handler
echo handle the error here
goto end

:done 
echo script completion code here

:end
@echo %Message%
pause
```

and it gives the following output:

```
IF ELSE DEMO
Msg 3701, Level 11, State 1, Server HERCULES, Line 1
Cannot drop the database 'Mytest', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
script completion code here
ECHO is off.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

## My expectation is:

1. if the database is available it should delete the database and should enter into :done code if the database is not available it should enter into :err_handler block.
2. I don't want Echo is off message.

Comment: Try adding a line `echo errorlevel=%errorlevel%` directly after the `sqlcmd...` line, which will show you the errorlevel returned. Convention is that 0=success, but conventions are sometimes broken. What errorlevel is  returned when you **successfully** delete a database? The `echo is off` is appearing because you are not assigning anything to `message` so `echo` will reports its status (off, since you execute `@echo off` first) - solution is to assign a value to `message`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It shows errorlevel=0 for both the cases (if DB is available, if the DB is not available)

Answer (score 6):

From [MS documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms162773.aspx):

> Error Reporting Options
>
> **-b**
>
> Specifies that sqlcmd exits and returns a DOS ERRORLEVEL value when 
>   an error occurs. The value that is returned to the DOS ERRORLEVEL
>   variable is 1 when the SQL Server error message has a severity level
>   greater than 10; otherwise, the value returned is 0. If the -V option
>   has been set in addition to -b, sqlcmd will not report an error if the
>   severity level is lower than the values set using -V. Command prompt
>   batch files can test the value of ERRORLEVEL and handle the error
>   appropriately. sqlcmd does not report errors for severity level 10
>   (informational messages).
>
> If the sqlcmd script contains an incorrect comment, syntax error, or 
>   is missing a scripting variable, ERRORLEVEL returned is 1.
>
> **-m error_level**
>
> Controls which error messages are sent to stdout. Messages that have 
>   a severity level greater than or equal to this level are sent.
>   When this value is set to -1, all messages including informational
>   messages, are sent. Spaces are not allowed between the -m and -1. For
>   example, -m-1 is valid, and -m -1 is not.
>
> This option also sets the sqlcmd scripting variable SQLCMDERRORLEVEL.
>   This variable has a default of 0.
>
> **-V error_severity_level**
>
> Controls the severity level that is used to set the ERRORLEVEL 
>   variable. Error messages that have severity levels greater than or
>   equal to this value set ERRORLEVEL. Values that are less than 0 are
>   reported as 0. Batch and CMD files can be used to test the value of
>   the ERRORLEVEL variable.

You will need to use the adecuated values to get a error from the database. Without them, the `errorlevel` you see is refered to the `sqlcmd` instance executed (should be `0` as it has been sucessfully executed), not the command running in the database.

Also, as already commented, the `ECHO is off.` message is generated by your

```
echo %Message%
```

with the variable undefined. The line is parsed and converted to

```
echo
```

as `%Message%` has no value. And the behaviour of `echo` command without parameters is to output the `echo` state.